# Attempting to preview form input jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to preview my name and step element in my form, so the user can see if they have made a mistake. I am able to preview the step however the name just won't work. Can anyone see why?

http://jsfiddle.net/pocockn/rw54b/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var commentNode = $('#lp-step'),
        nameNode = $('#lp-name'),
        name = $('#name');



    $('#live-preview-form input, #live-preview-form textarea').bind('blur keyup',function() {



        commentNode.text($('#step_1').val());
        commentNode.html($('#lp-step').html().replace(/\n/g,'<br />'));

    if($('#name').val()) {
        nameNode.text(name.val() + ' says:');

    }
    else {
        return false;
    }


    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post the associated HTML as well? would be helpful

Comment: See in console "Uncaught ReferenceError: Preview is not defined "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two elements with the same `ID`, if you do it will only select the first element it finds. (in this case its the div which is always empty and never runs your if statement). You have your `div` with `id=name` and your `input`.  So I changed your div id to `nameDiv` instead.

`Id's should be unique to avoid confusion.`

```
<div id="nameDiv">
    <label for="name">Enter recipe name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <br />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/rw54b/1/